# Making an emergency call in Android 2.1

Tags: android

Can I make an emergency call programmatically in Android 2.1?

I've tried to use something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(telUri));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
appCtx.startActivity(intent);
```

but the only thing that I can do is call the system dialpad with the specified emergency number.

I have to push the 'dial' button to make call. Is there any way to skip the dialer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.  The phone activity (actually part of the Contacts application) is what responds to the `ACTION_CALL` intent and you can't change how it handles it.  This is done specifically to make sure the user confirms the number he/she wishes to dial.